# How to verify the users connected and how many requests they are doing on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, slackware

How can I check on my MySQL server the follow:

1. what accounts have an open connection to the mysql-server ?
2. how often they request a new connection ?
3. how many requests they usually do per connection ?

---

It would be nice if I could aswell identify the codes that are making the calls aswell like, let's say:

/home/domainX/public_html/db.pl or /home/domainX/public_html/index.php

I guess this last part is only available if it is a socket call right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what accounts have an open connection to the mysql-server ?

mysqladmin processlist

> how often they request a new connection ?

Not sure - try the General Query log - but I suspect it may not record connections - only queries

> how many requests they usually do per connection ?

See above.

> It would be nice if I could aswell identify the codes that are making the calls aswell

The socket architecture does not allow for this deterministically - you can only get this from an assertion by the client program or by partitioning the code to use different authentication details.

> I guess this last part is only available if it is a socket call right ?

Eh? That question makes no sense. There is no way to connect to a mysql **other** than using a socket.

Comment: Thanks for you helpfull answers :) about the last reply by socket i was pointing that if an user connects from another ip to the mysql i would not be able to get any information as to what code was used i was thinking it would be a local type of info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using mtop at  http://mtop.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I am looking for commands within mysql but thanks.